# Holding 12-inch tiles together to build planter

Tags: tile

I have a bunch of 12" tiles and I want to build a few planters/pots with them. I've googled quite a bit, and I really liked this [instructables link](https://www.instructables.com/Fast-Easy-Tile-Planter/) since it's easier for one person to stand up all 4 tiles.

In the instructions, he holds the upright tiles together using *"weave fabric reinforcing (fiberglass drywall tape)"*.

In my case, these planters will be filled with soil, which will make them a bit heavy. So I'm wondering if this fiberglass drywall tape is strong enough.

Is this weave fabric reinforcing/fiberglass drywall tape that strong?

Or if you guys have ideas on how to hold these 4 tiles together (or any other ideas), it will be greatly appreciated.

I posted this here because it's more of a *construction* question rather than a gardening question.

Comment: I would like flat clean section of the tile edges to get max holding.  I would not recommend trying to move them with them filled with dirt.

Comment: Why don't you just try it?  Any ideas will just be opinions, which don't do well here.

Comment: Pretty sure drywall mesh isn’t designed to withstand uv…

Comment: For the small amount of effort in testing this out, that really seems to be the way to go, though I'd expect this to fail...

Answer (score 7):

Tiles are not structural. Whatever you use to join them together will either fail, or the tiles will fail. And then you will have a giant mess.

You should instead build a wooden box or frame and use construction adhesive to attach the tiles. That way the wood is doing the real work of holding things together.

Put a real pot inside to hold the dirt. Or line it with heavy plastic. You don't want dirt and moisture in contact with the wood.

Comment: That is probably the best way of doing this, but when the wood expands and contracts, it would crack the tiles.  Outdoor wood is the most unstable.  Plywood could minimize this problem but they don't hold well outside.